# Handling ActiveRecord Results - No Record Found

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, activerecord

How can I prevent my controller from throwing errors when an ActiveRecord query does not return a result?

```
 ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound in PasswordResetsController#edit
 Couldn't find User with password_reset_token = rqZEGQUH54390Pg-AUC5Q
```

I thought that the "!" symbol would produce a 404 but at least in development, it displays the error trace in the browser.

Will this method below produce a 404 in production, if the query returns nothing?

If not, how can I fix?

Thanks

```
    def edit
      @user = user.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
    end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With the `rescue` clause:

```
def edit
  @user = user.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound => e
  # Do something with error, 'e'
end
```

Or with `rescue_from` in the controller (can be reused across multiple actions:

```
rescue_from ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound, with: lambda do |e|
  # Do something with error, 'e'
end

def edit
  @user = user.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])
end
```

In answer to your other question, it will give an HTTP 404 error in production but it will not show a stack trace. By default it shows a very basic error page that says something went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
 class PasswordResetsController
   def edit
     ...
     begin
      @user = user.find_by_password_reset_token!(params[:id])

     rescue ActiveRecord::RecordNotFound  
      redirect_to :controller => "{Your Controller}", :action => "{Your Action}"
      return
     end
    end
   end
```